# HTML Set IP for hostname to load resources

Tags: javascript, html, dns

A method to define IP for hostname to be used when loading assets to avoid dns resolve.

example: set host.com ip = 1.2.3.4

```
<img src="http://host.com/img.png">
<img src="http://host.com/img2.png">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://host.com/script.js">
```

I want "host.com" to resolve to "1.2.3.4" regardless the real ip in user browser DNS.

I know about "dns-prefetch", but is it possible to modify the address response?

like:

```
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="http://host.com/" address="1.2.3.4">
```

Comment: Just use the IP address instead of the host name?

Comment: I can't think of a reason for writing an HTML file that has `href` showing `host.com` but to not use `host.com`'s actual IP to fetch the resources that isn't...a bit off, to put it mildly. If you want to do this for local testing or something, modify your `/etc/hosts` file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows).

Comment: of course using `<img src="http://1.2.3.4/img.png">` will not work because the remote server works only with "Host: host.com" which can't be passed here.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I had the same thought, but perhaps this is some sort of attempt to hide the JS source code. Which wouldn't work even if this trick would work somehow..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I want to set it on website for visitors, something like load balancing.

Comment: Javascript is client side code. Which means that the user's browser must download it in order for it to work (temporary internet files). No matter what you try to obfuscate or hide it, the user will have access to your Javascript source code and will be able to make it readable. If you want to load balance, there's no reason to try and hide the source of where the Javascript is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to set it on website for visitors, something like load balancing.

You can't. Instead, either use a proper load balancer on `host.com`, or produce the images et. al. dynamically using `a.host.com`, `b.host.com`, `c.host.com`, etc.

You might do that dynamicness via the [`base` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-base-element), which:

> ...allows authors to specify the document base URL for the purposes of parsing URLs, and the name of the default browsing context for the purposes of following hyperlinks.

So right at the top of your document, prior to any element that will have a URL to resolve, perhaps:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var hosts = ["a.host.com", "b.host.com", "c.host.com"/*...or whatever their names are...*/];
    var host = hosts[Math.floor(hosts.length * Math.random())];
    var base = document.createElement("base");
    base.href = "http://" + host + "/";
    document.querySelector("head").appendChild(base);
})();
</script>
```

Then the links would be

```
<img src="img.png">
<img src="img2.png">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
```

Just beware that `base` affects **all** links in the document.

Answer (score 0):

No. [There is no `address` attribute on the `link` element in HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-link-element).

Nor is that what the [`dns-prefetch`](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/#dns-prefetch) link type meant to be used for. It is meant to tell the browser to do the DNS resolution of the domain name ahead of time. That is it.

There is also no method to tell the browser to do DNS resolution differently from a webpage that is loaded by the browser. That would be a fundamental breach of security.